# Btrbck Error: Not a BTRFS Filesystem?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, filesystem, btrfs

I have installed my Kubuntu 18.04 system using a manual partitioning scheme and chose BTRFS in the install screen. This is confirmed using the `disks` utility.

However, when I try to follow this tutorial (https://github.com/ruediste/btrbck#btrbck) for taking snapshot of the filesystem, it comes up with this error (Note, I followed the instructions in order that they specified):

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS Backups$ sudo btrbck create BackupStream
ERROR: not a btrfs filesystem: /home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS Backups
```

Disks:

[image]

**Edit 0:** Retried with no space folder name, same result.

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS_Backups$ sudo btrbck create -a
Created application repository in /home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS_Backups                                        
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS_Backups$ sudo btrbck create BackupStream                            
ERROR: not a btrfs filesystem: /home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS_Backups                                           
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating sub volume in /home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/BTRFS_Backups/BackupStream                                                                                                
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.BtrfsService.createSubVolume(BtrfsService.java:85)                                    
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.StreamService.createStream(StreamService.java:134)                                    
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.cli.CliMain.cmdCreate(CliMain.java:430)                                               
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.cli.CliMain.processCommand(CliMain.java:141)                                          
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.cli.CliMain.doMain(CliMain.java:113)                                                  
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:100)                                                    
Caused by: java.io.IOException: exit code: 1                                                                                 
    at com.github.ruediste1.btrbck.BtrfsService.createSubVolume(BtrfsService.java:54)                                    
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Why do you have `BTRFS Backups` instead of something like `BTRFS_Backups` or `BTRFS-Backups`. In other words, why the space? I'm not saying the space in the path is the problem in this case, but spaces in file or folder names can bite you at some unexpected time.

Comment: @DKBose Hmm, I wouldn't think it would be mandatory. Software tools should be able to parse such basic formatting. It could be, I'll run it tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: If you're interested, please see [Filenames: What's In A Name?](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201607/page03.html). Again, possibly nothing to do with your issue but of general interest.